# SQL Max function is returning two results although just one of them is needed

Tags: sql, max

I'm attempting to return the last unit price for an item based on the last_order_date. However, since there are two unit prices, two lines are returned. How do I get it to ignore the unit_price and just base it on the last_order_date? In my case I would need just the first result returned. Thanks in advance!

Result:

2021-01-13  110352  101320  101320  251.17  2021

2021-01-12  110352  101320  101320  243.86  2021

```
SELECT   MAX(order_date) AS last_order_date, inv_mast_uid, Bill_To_ID, Ship_To_ID, unit_price, Order_Year
FROM     dbo.[my_table]
GROUP BY inv_mast_uid, Bill_To_ID, Ship_To_ID, Order_Year, unit_price
HAVING   (Order_Year = 2021)
```

Comment: what DB are you using. Does it support window function?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT last_order_date, inv_mast_uid, Bill_To_ID, Ship_To_ID, Order_Year, unit_price
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(order_date) as last_order_date
    FROM dbo.[my_table]
    WHERE Order_Year = 2021
) a
JOIN dbo.[my_table] b ON 
    a.last_order_date = b.order_date
GROUP BY last_order_date, inv_mast_uid, Bill_To_ID, Ship_To_ID, Order_Year, unit_price
```

Get the last_order_date within a subquery, then joining the table onto itself to only get the rows you need.

Depending on what your data looks like, you may not even need to use the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT TOP (1) t.*
FROM dbo.[my_table] t
WHERE order_year = 2021
ORDER BY order_date DESC;
```

I am using `TOP` because the `dbo` and square braces suggest SQL Server.

I also suspect that you want to restrict this to a single item, so that should be in the `WHERE` clause as well.

EDIT:

If you want one row per item with the most recent data, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <item id> ORDER BY order_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.[my_table] t
      WHERE order_year = 2021
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

It is not clear how "item" is defined in the table.  Your question is not clear on that point.

Comment: This works great for one item but there are more than one items in my table. The above was just an example of one item. Sorry for not being clear. Is there a way to return for all items? Thanks!

Comment: @JMauras . . . You can use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.

Comment: Thank you but it's still pulling back just the TOP 1 of the table

SELECT        TOP (1) WITH TIES last_order_date, inv_mast_uid, Bill_To_ID, Ship_To_ID, unit_price, Order_Year
FROM            dbo.[table] AS t
ORDER BY last_order_date DESC